# How to test in J-Unit when a method returns null?

Tags: java, jpa, junit, mockito, converters

They are my methods and I am testing them: It is fine when I dont give null as parameter but I can not test when I give my parameter as null? I cant unterstand the logic of it.

Thats my converter methods:

```
 @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(WorkerId id) {
        if (Assert.isNull(id)) {
            return null;
        }
        return id.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public WorkerId convertToEntityAttribute(Integer s) {
        if (Assert.isNull(s)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new WorkerId(s);
    }
```

and thats my test methods:

```
@Test
public void testConvertToDatabaseColumn() {
    WorkerId workerId = new WorkerId(1);
    Integer result = workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(workerId);
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(workerId.getValue());
}

@Test
public void testIfIdNull() {
    WorkerId workerId = null;
    Integer result = workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(workerId);
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(null));
}
```

Comment: why can't you test when you give null as parameter?

Comment: is this right or is my logic okay or is it stupid? `assertThat(result).isEqualTo(workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(null));`

Comment: you are testing that method 2 times in 1 testcase. read davidxxxs answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need and should not invoke twice the method to test.
That is enough :

```
@Test
public void testIfIdNull() {
    WorkerId workerId = null;
    Integer result = workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(workerId);
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(null);
}
```

Or more simply without matcher (that is not helpful here):

```
@Test
public void testIfIdNull() {
    WorkerId workerId = null;
    Integer result = workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(workerId);
    Assert.assertNull(result);
}
```

And as the assertion and the method to test are concise, you could even write all in a single line without decreasing the readability:

```
@Test
public void testIfIdNull() {
    Assert.assertNull(workerIdConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(null));
}
```